# Drawing elliptic curve over finite field

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've seen a lot of helpful information here for drawing elliptic curves over the reals, but I'm having trouble doing the same over a finite field.
For example, let's say we try to draw the points on
E: y^2 = x^3 + 1 with x,y in the field of 17 elements.

I tried some combinations of

```
\foreach \x in {1,...,16}
\foreach \y in {1,...,16}{ 
    let \lhs = {int(mod(\y*\y, 17))}
    let \rhs = {int(mod(\x*\x*\x + 1,17))}
    \ifthenelse{\lhs = \rhs}{
    \node[circle,draw] (\x \y) at (\x,\y) {\x};
    }{}
}
```

but I never really get it to work... The image should become similar to
[image: Text]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `let` outside of a path.
Just use [`\pgfmathsetmacro\lhr{…}`](https://tikz.dev/math-parsing#%5Cpgfmathsetmacro) (or in this case `\pgfmathtruncatemacro\lhr{…}` and dropping the `int` function) or the [`evaluate` key](https://tikz.dev/pgffor#pgf/foreach/evaluate) for `\foreach`.

I've adjusted the node style a bit and added the  values `\x` and `\y` as a label so that you can check the the evaluated points.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every label/.append style={font=\small}]
\foreach[
  evaluate={\rhs = int(mod(\x*\x*\x + 1, 17));}
] \x in {1,...,16}{
  \foreach[
    evaluate={\lhs = int(mod(\y*\y, 17));}
  ] \y in {1,...,16}{
    \ifthenelse{\lhs = \rhs}{
      \node[circle, red, fill, label={\x, \y}] at (\x,\y) {};
    }{}
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]